# Alternative way of using an icon font

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I tried to avoid {`<i>`} and :before classes in my html/css. So, i ended up using this way:

```
**CSS**

@font-face {
  font-family: "mtv";
  src:url("fonts/mtv.eot");
  src:url("fonts/mtv.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("fonts/mtv.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/mtv.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/mtv.svg#mtv") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

}

.iFont{
    font-family: "mtv";
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #269AE0;
}

HTML

<div class="iFont">a</div>
```

Do you think that it will be problematic for some reason?

Comment: Why did you try to avoid `<i>`?

Comment: Semantically, i think div is more close to the actual use (icon) of the element. On the other hand, this does not apply to the content of the div. This is why i am not sure if this is a proper way to use an icon font.

Comment: Sematically, a `span` would be better than a `div` but that just an opinion..

Comment: I think `<i>` is used because it is an inline element and wraps the text within a paragraph. And it's an `i`, like in `icon`.

Answer (score 0):

No, its perfectly fine because you have used `font-face` above and then applying a `font-family` in a div containing only text will not create any problem.
Above code will work perfectly fine. Go ahead!